# Kerberos key fails with AutoFS

Tags: automounting, cifs, kerberos, autofs

Our Kubuntu computers are configured to automatically connect to their network drive via AutoFS. When we upgrade machines to **Kubuntu 18.04 LTS** this AutoFS connection no longer works. It is still working fine in Kubuntu 14.04 LTS and Kubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I have run autoFS (automount) in debug mode:

> automount -f -d

.. and receive the following error:

```
mount error(126): Required key not available
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

I can use klist and see a kerberos key is present but still won't map (why?)

Now after some fooling around the kerberos key now works reliably only in debug mode (automount -f -d). It doesn't work at all when run as a service (service autofs start). Why does it only work in debug mode..?

Here is the error in daemon.log :

```
May 16 17:49:02 computer1234 cifs.upcall: get_cachename_from_process_env: pathname=/proc/1234/environ  
May 16 17:49:02 computer1234 cifs.upcall: get_existing_cc: default ccache is FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_12345678  
May 16 17:49:02 computer1234 cifs.upcall: get_tgt_time: unable to get principal  
May 16 17:49:02 computer1234 cifs.upcall: krb5_get_init_creds_keytab: -1765328174  
May 16 17:49:02 computer1234 cifs.upcall: Exit status 1
```

I had tried adding '-t' in /etc/request-key.d/cifs.spnego.conf and it still was not working

If you have similar problem you can try adding *logging = "verbose"* or *logging = "debug"* in /etc/autofs.conf to get more detail.

Yesterday we noticed that autofs is looking for the kerberos ticket file named in this format:

> /tmp/krb5cc_12345678

However the actual kerberos ticket file name has 7 more chars at the end and looks like this:

> /tmp/krb5cc_12345678_1A23B4

Answer (score 1):

As per **UPDATE 2** above, the issue was that autofs is looking for a kerberos ticket named in this format:

```
 /tmp/krb5cc_12345678
```

But the actual kerberos ticket was named in this format:

```
/tmp/krb5cc_12345678_1A23B4
```

To fix the file names edit /etc/sssd/sssd.conf and add the following under the relevant domain section, ie. under [domain/yourAD_ServerName]

```
krb5_ccname_template=FILE:%d/krb5cc_%U
```

I had to reboot in order to get these changes to take effect. I tried restarting sssd-secrets, sssd, and autofs but that wasn't enough. Only after a reboot were the filenames in the right format, and then autofs worked properly in Kubuntu 18.04 LTS.